# How to make an animated skybox in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a world in which there will be a black hole instead of the sun. I want to animate this black hole, but I do not know how to do it.
[Example of a black hole](https://tenor.com/view/black-hole-%E9%BB%91%E6%B4%9E-crazy-galaxy-science-gif-15142382)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how you want to animate, but you can create your own skybox material or use one of the default ones and change its variables in code. I guess you can call the skybox material with `RenderSettings.skybox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is render a 360 video in a external video editor (many tutorials on that), then you can import the video into Unity as a movie texture. Then apply that to the skybox material.